# How can I use session to display a modal message?

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I would like to know how could I use a session variable to define a message and display it on the next page.

I have created a base template that I extend in all templates. I inserted the modal message code to check if there is any message in the base template

My base template(base.html)

```
...
{% if request.session.message %}
        <div id="modalAlert">
            <div class="modal-backdrop"></div>
            <div class="modal" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        ×
                    </button>
                    <h3>{{ request.session.title }}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        {{ request.session.message }}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#" id="botao-fechar" class="btn">Ok</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#modalAlert').show();
            $('#myModal button.close,#myModal #botao-fechar').click(function() {
                $('#modalAlert').hide();
            })

        </script>

        {% endif %}
  ...
```

And in my view I have inserted the message in session

```
 def home(request):
    request.session.message = 'Test message'
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response("professor/home.html", context_instance)
```

However doesn't appear the message, there is nothing in the session. I have tested the modal and it is okay. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Other than not using the Messages framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add **django.core.context_processors.request** to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings so you can access request from template, default settings does not include this, so your message won't show.

Why not use Django default message framework?

Comment: I have added it however my statics files such css and js are not being loaded anymore :(

Comment: I was missing some context processors for static, I tried default message framework and It works great. Thank you